# Clicking "Run", "Search","Help and Support" in Start Menu Problems

Tags: shortcuts, start-menu

I've got a problem with my start menu.

I was playing a bit deleting some context menu entries. Now every time I click the "Run","Search" or "Help and Support" icons I get:

> "Windows Cannot create a shortcut here, Do you want the shortcut to be placed on the desktop instead? YES OR NO".

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late for you, but I got the same problem and it was fixed by running:

```
sfc /SCANNOW
```

from the run window - you may need your original (or somebody else's) XP disc.